# Network Data Allowance

Tags: networking, router

I'm looking at getting a new router for my home but I need to have a way of setting up user IDs with a couple of devices per user ID and setup data allowances per ID then split that allowance up per device

I've been looking at an open-wrt compatible router to do this but haven't found much on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern routers have such features built in.  Have you looked at the manual for a few routers? Asus AC86U has a "Bandwidth Limiter- helps you to control download and upload max speed of your cleint devices."  This is part of the QoS subsystem.  A few mouse clicks and you are done.  The Asus device even had a graphical interface to monitor specific use to optimize the system.

Most other current routers will have similar features.  Entry level, low cost routers likely not so much.

More research would guide you specifically for what is available in your market.  While DD-WRT may be an option you will likely find what you need in the OS that ships on the router.